# How to delay gifs from starting on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, delay, gif

I have an animated gif that I would like to delay when it start on page load. I was wondering if this was possible to do?

So for example, the page loads, and I would want the gif to start after x amount of seconds pass.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure of a way of controlling Gif's, but one idea is to have a Gif with just the first frame inside, and then swap the Gif's after x amount of seconds.

Comment: There are different ways that you can do this. You can place the delay into the gif itself - OR - You could have an image of the first frame of the gif which you have a timer that displays that image for however long you want then you replace it with the animated gif after time or when ever someone hovers over.

This also means that the heavy load gifs can load in the background while the page loads with the lower sized images giving you better page load

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the display property from none to block. combining with css animation delay to trigger your delay time . Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question was posted a long time ago, but
you can use this website to give your gif a delay after the first frame:

https://ezgif.com/maker